# How to get Table View to scroll above Image View?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uiimageview

I'm using a table and image in my program.
I placed the image on top and table just below that.
Now I need to keep the Image static and On scrolling I want the table to go above the image according to the scroll height.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use the `contentInset` of your `UITableView` to adjust the initial offset of the content. Make sure your tableView is front of your UIImageView.

```
[self.tableView setContentInset:UIEdgeInsetsMake(viewHeight, 0, 0, 0)];
```

`contentInset` will only adjust the initial content position, so when scrolling, the whole frame of your UITableView is used.

[image]

**Update**: UIView is UIImageView in your case

Comment: Now the scroll is working fine.. we get that h height also.. problem is my image view is getting hidden.. even though the h height is there,it's not usable... If i try to place my image view in front,table won't scroll above the  image..if i set table view above the image view,table view takes the whole space and hides my imageview

Comment: what do you mean? Can't you set the backgroundColor of the tableView and its cells in the tableView to clearColor?

Comment: How will I place my image view in that height "h" ??

Comment: Use a UIViewController, not UITableViewController. Add the UITableView as subview, set its delegate and datasource to your UIViewController. Add the subview to the viewController.view (not has tableHeaderView of your tableView)

Comment: I'm using a UIViewController in that I have 3 subviews, i.e SearchBar, below that I have a ImageView and below that I have a TableView. Now when I set the contentInset,the image view which was there in that height h goes behind the table and the table takes up that height.But it doesn't display anything.Actual contents starts after the height h.

Comment: the imageView has to be below the UITableView. As in the picture, the tableView has to have the same origin position as your imageView

Comment: yes, the tableView is supposed to be on top of the imageView. Just set the backgroundColor to clearColor, so that the image is still visible

Comment: The problem what I'm facing is when I place image view below the tableview.The table takes up that image views height and give a blank space there. Since tableview also have the same origin as image view and since its above the image view,image view is getting hidden

Comment: if you set the backgroundColor of the tableHeaderView, tableView, tableView.contentView to UIColor.clearColor it should work

Comment: Table header is not getting scrolled,only the cells are getting  scrolled above the image view.The table header is at its initial position.Im using custom tableviewcells. Will i have to change the table style?

Comment: I did it by changing the table style.

Answer (score 0):

You can use it by Placing both the `UIImageView` and `UITableView` in `UIScrollView`

And set `UIScrollView contentSize()` according to need like

1.) `scrollView.scontentSize = CGSizeMake(scrollView.frame.size.width, imageView.frame.size.height + tableView.frame.size.height + 10);`

2.) Set `UITableView` scrolling to NO

This would help you.ThankYou